# How to disable automatic date-linking on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, date, mobile, responsive-design

I'm currently developing an RWD site, and while testing on the iPhone4 I see that plain dates are "seen" as phone-numbers - hence clickable. I do not want that.

This is a Norwegian site with dates written in format: DD.MM.YYYY (8 numbers).
Norwegian phone-numbers also contain 8 numbers.

For instance: The date 23.11.2011 (23rd November 2011). On pc and android, this is given the correct CSS for dates, but the iPhone shows these as "links". When clicked the iphone (iOS) prompts me with a call dialog box "23 11 20 11 - Call or Cancel ". Why?

The really weird thing is, that this is not consistent. Take this code for example:

`<span class="pubDate">(Published: 24.10.2011, Last changed: 02.12.2011)</span>`

On my iPhone, only the last-changed-date is clickable, not the first one.
Does anyone know of a way to make these unclickable for iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, and most thorough way, is to simply use the meta tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

This prevents iOS from parsing numbers and converting assumed-numbers into clickable/callable numbers.

If, on the other hand, you want to prevent numbers being styled as links, you can use the following CSS selectors to target those links that start with the `tel:` protocol:

```
a[href^=tel] {
    /* stlyes links that start with the 'tel' protocol */
}
```

Reference:

- [Apple-specific `meta` tags](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).